# Loops with no body,i got the code from a book but i dont understand the math in the code

Tags: java

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i;
        int sum=0;

        for(i=1;i<=5;sum+=i++)
            System.out.println(sum);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Actual Output:**`15`

I don't know how it did the math?

Comment: Try to understand it then post question on anything specific you are not able to understand . Sorry to say this but nobody will help you with such blanket questions 

Comment: Explain exactly what you have to understand in the code?

Comment: this *can* be good for testing knowledge, but is a better example of what to avoid when coding IMHO - does not describe very well what is intended, more like hiding it. (I've emphasized the *can* because I do not really believe this kind of testing)

Answer (score 2):

The [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-BasicForStatement) for the `for` loop is:

```
for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
```

and is basically equivalent with the following `while` loop:

```
[ForInit]
while (Expression) {
    Statement
    [ForUpdate]
}
```

That mean that all the following are the same:

```
for(i=1;i<=5;sum+=i++);
```

```
i = 1;
while (i <= 5) {
    sum += i++;
}
```

```
i = 1;
while (i <= 5) {
    sum += i;
    i++;
}
```

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    sum += i;
```

So it is calculating `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15`

Answer (score 1):

What confuses you is the part

```
sum += i++
```

In this statement, first `sum=sum+i` gets calculated. Once `sum` has been calculated, value of `i` is incremented by `1`.

Since the loop runs five times, previous value of `sum` gets added to current value of `i`, which keeps increases by 1.

Comment: I think he's just confused that the loop doesn't have "{" and "}".

Comment: *"Once sum has been calculated, value of i is incremented by 1"* Technically incorrect. The value of `i` is incremented *before* the value of `sum` is updated, but it does use the value of `i` from before the increment.

Comment: That sounds counter intuitive to me, but you may be right. Any further reading material on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out each iteration through the loop to help you visualise what is going on. Swap your for loop for this.

```
for(i=1;i<=5;sum+=i++)
            {
                System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code, the statement sum+ = i++ means sum = sum + i++ In this statement, every sum printed in the loop adds to one increment of i and when the loop ends it will display 15.
So it is calculating 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15